# jQuery bootstrap datatable search and sort doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I got this code partial working. ajax code was able to fetch json data from server. But the search function and sort function doesn't work. Here is my js code. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,
            responsive: true,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax"      : "getData3.php",
                "columns"   : [
                   { "data" : "id"},
                   { "data" : "sales_license"},
                   { "data" : "first_name" },
                   { "data" : "last_name" },
                   { "data" : "email"}
                ],



            buttons: [
                //{extend: 'copy'},
                //{extend: 'csv'},
                //{extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile'},
                //{extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile'},

                  {extend: 'print',
                 customize: function (win){
                        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                        $(win.document.body).find('table')
                                .addClass('compact')
                                .css('font-size', 'inherit');

                }
                }
            ]

        });
});
```

Comment: You probably have big red errors in the console. Check those out.

Comment: Sorry what do you meant by big red errors in the console.

Comment: Try pressing F12, look for a "console" pane - then hit F5.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issues. I need to comments out the following lines.

```
            //"processing": true,
            //"serverSide": true,
```

now the code work. The reason being the searching and sorting are done on client side not on server side.